# how to add class to `li` tag in fancy tree jquery

Tags: jquery, css, fancytree

How to add class to `li` tag in fancy tree jquery.
I tried using `extraClasses` but it adds the class to the span tag can anyone help me?

```
 {title: "Node 2", folder: true, lazy: true, 
        treeMode: "struct", 
        keyType: "root", key: "_structtree_", 
        refKey: "_structtree_", 
        extraClasses: "scioStructureTree" }
```

Please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a similar problem when restyling fancytree. I have found a solution after studying the source code of fancytree

```
$("<selector to your html element>").fancytree({
   ... other stuff ...
   renderNode: function(event, data) {
      setTimeout(function() {
          $(node.li).addClass("your className")
      }, 20);
   }
})
```

The 20 ms timeout makes sure that the node is fully rendered, so the classes aren't removed with the rendering.

You can use node.li as a normal javascript object, $(node.li) as a normal JQuery object